# Why do some classes of a library need to be included and not others?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, linker-errors, open3d

**Starting Point**

I have a C++ application (working with VS2019, Window 10 64bit), which heavily relies on the [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/) library. Everything was working perfectly fine, I was using the previous version (0.14.x), which I built from source using CMAKE and Visual Studio 2019.

There are some features in the new version (0.15.1) I would like to use. Furthermore, new releases come with a binary packages, so no more building from source. So I backup my current version and download the new binaries and try to link them to my project.

**Issue**

To start from a clean slate I remove all the old entries for Open3D and manually insert the new ones. Here are the entries:

*Project Properties --> C/C++ --> General --> Additional Include Directories:*

- C:\Open3D\include
- C:\Open3D\include\open3d\3rdparty
- other stuff

*Project Properties --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies:*

- C:\Open3D\lib\Open3D.lib
- other stuff

Building now leads to a whole lot of linker errors all connected to `fmt`, a 3rd party library used by Open3D it seems. However, these seem to be caused only because, I have two additional includes with respect to Open3D in my precompiled header:

```
// open3d
#include "open3d/Open3D.h"
#include "open3d/core/Indexer.h"
#include "open3d/t/geometry/RaycastingScene.h"
```

If I remove them, all linking errors disappear, but I'm facing yet another issue: `Indexer.h` is needed for the [`TensorIterator` class](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/cpp_api/classopen3d_1_1core_1_1_tensor_iterator.html), `RaycastingScene.h` for the [`RaycastingScene` class](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/cpp_api/classopen3d_1_1t_1_1geometry_1_1_raycasting_scene.html), both of which I'm using a lot in my project.

**Question(s)**

Why do I need an extra import for `RaycastingScene` but not for example `VoxelblockGrid`, which is in the same namespace?
I have already tried to clone, build and link `fmt` manually. It looks like I can access the library from my own code successfully, but using Open3D I still get the same linker errors.
How am I supposed to use these two classes?

Comment: What is the exact linker error you get connected to `fmt` (show the first one).  Guessing you just need to add the fmt library to your list of dependencies.

Comment: @LouFranco one of the error messages is for example `HDrRenderer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int const * const fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::zero_or_powers_of_10_32" (?zero_or_powers_of_10_32@?$basic_data@X@internal@v6@fmt@@2QBIB)`

Comment: Found this issue: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/1193. 
Adding `#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY` in my precompiled header seemed to do the trick. I'm facing some other issues now, however the linker errors are resolved and the code is building again at least! :)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Defining the `FMT_HEADER_ONLY` allows you to use fmt as a header-only library rather than linking the binary. This seems like it should be the responsibility of the dependent, which in this case is Open3D. Your code should not have to do this. If Open3D doesn't define this flag (which it clearly doesn't), then it expects fmt to be linked. The proper solution on your end should be to link it. You've already tried doing that, but maybe you missed a subtle detail? The linker error you're getting seems like a plain old "you didn't link this" linker error.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer yes thank you for the answer, makes a lot of sense. My basic question however is: Why does Open3D's `RaycastingScene` need the extra import in the first place. I can use other classes in the library's same namespace by simply importing Open3D itself. What is the clue to why some classes work without additional imports, while others don't?

Comment: A namespace has nothing to do with including files. It's just a way of grouping and organizing classes, functions, etc. For instance, `vector` and `cout` are both in the `std` namespace. But `#include <iostream>` does not give you access to the `vector` class. Why would it? Vectors have nothing to do with I/O; it would be upsetting if the entire standard namespace had to be imported just so that I could write to standard out. But the files that you include might also include other files in turn. So maybe you've accidentally included `VoxelblockGrid` transitively, and that's why it works fine.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer thanks. Coming from C# I'm used to think in terms of how `using namespace` works there...hard to shake of :) 
So basically there is no simple way to say if a class is already imported through another import, except by testing (or hoping the docs include the info)?

Comment: You should assume that it's *not* imported transitively. The standard practice is to make imports idempotent, which is to say that if you `#include` the same file twice, the second action is a no-op. So there's no harm in importing the file twice. Even if it *has* been transitively imported (which you might determine by testing, as you suggest), a future update to the package might no longer need that transitive import due to changes in implementation details, so it might remove it. If you're not also importing it manually in your own code, then your code will break.

Comment: Also if you have a precompiled header (pch), depending on the implementation, it just includes everything listed in the pch in all of your files. This leads to the behavior, that nothing included in the pch HAS to be included for your project to compile. You should anyway in case pch breaks, pch handling differs, or your build system does not support pch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A namespace has nothing to do with including files. It's just a way of grouping and organizing classes, functions, etc. For instance, vector and cout are both in the std namespace. But #include  does not give you access to the vector class. Why would it? Vectors have nothing to do with I/O; it would be upsetting if the entire standard namespace had to be imported just so that I could write to standard out. But the files that you include might also include other files in turn. So maybe you've accidentally included VoxelblockGrid transitively, and that's why it works fine.

You should assume that it's not imported transitively. The standard practice is to make imports idempotent, which is to say that if you #include the same file twice, the second action is a no-op. So there's no harm in importing the file twice. Even if it has been transitively imported (which you might determine by testing, as you suggest), a future update to the package might no longer need that transitive import due to changes in implementation details, so it might remove it. If you're not also importing it manually in your own code, then your code will break.